AzureML: 'OSError: No space left on device'
I am training a computer vision model using AzureML.
After struggling to submit a Job via the Python SDK, I followed the idea of this answer by uploading the code directly into the blob, in my case using Azure Storage explorer as I am facing issues with azcopy on Ubuntu:
I created a folder inside the AzureML storage account where my code is uploaded to, so this works fine, I can submit the job.
Now, when trying to save a .pth checkpoint file, I get: 'OSError: No space left on device'.
The file in question causing this error shows a size of 15455054(.pth)

The data is in an ADLS Gen2, Hot Tier
Azure ML storage account 100TiB file share
File sizes: 269480 (.log), 5791616(.pth), 15455054(.pth), 17989(.py)
Compute: Standard_NC24ads_A100_v4

Job:
training_job = command(
    inputs={
        'data':Input(
                type="uri_folder",
                path=f"{data_asset.id}",
                mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT
        )},
    outputs={
        'outputs':Output(
            type='uri_folder',
            path = f'azureml://datastores/workspaceartifactstore/paths/ExperimentRun/dcid.{command_name}/outputs',
            mode  =InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT
        )},
    code=f'https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/job1-data/code/',
    command='python train.py',
    environment="{name}{version}".format(name=az_cfg['environment']['name'],version=az_cfg['environment']['version']),
    display_name=az_cfg['job']['display_name_train'],
    compute = ci_name,
    environment_variables={ 
      "DATASET_MOUNT_BLOCK_BASED_CACHE_ENABLED": True,
      "EXPERIMENT_NAME":az_cfg['mlflow']['experiment_name']
      },
    experiment_name=az_cfg['mlflow']['experiment_name'],
    name=command_name
      
)

I had training runs before with many more and larger files generated.
Any help in solving this issue is highly appreciated.
Edit:
I am using MMPose and MMEngine. (https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmengine/blob/main/mmengine/fileio/backends/local_backend.py#L60)
The snippet where the checkpoint is being saved is:
    def put(self, obj: bytes, filepath: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
        """Write bytes to a given ``filepath`` with 'wb' mode.

        Note:
            ``put`` will create a directory if the directory of
            ``filepath`` does not exist.

        Args:
            obj (bytes): Data to be written.
            filepath (str or Path): Path to write data.

        Examples:
            >>> backend = LocalBackend()
            >>> filepath = '/path/of/file'
            >>> backend.put(b'hello world', filepath)
        """
        mmengine.mkdir_or_exist(osp.dirname(filepath))
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(obj)

The error message:
File "src/train.py", line 219, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/train.py", line 204, in main
    runner.train()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1777, in train
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 102, in run
    self.runner.val_loop.run()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 375, in run
    self.runner.call_hook('after_val_epoch', metrics=metrics)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1839, in call_hook
    getattr(hook, fn_name)(self, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/hooks/checkpoint_hook.py", line 361, in after_val_epoch
    self._save_best_checkpoint(runner, metrics)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/hooks/checkpoint_hook.py", line 579, in _save_best_checkpoint
    self._save_checkpoint_with_step(runner, cur_time, meta)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/hooks/checkpoint_hook.py", line 443, in _save_checkpoint_with_step
    runner.save_checkpoint(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/dist/utils.py", line 427, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 2271, in save_checkpoint
    save_checkpoint(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/checkpoint.py", line 793, in save_checkpoint
    file_backend.put(f.getvalue(), filename)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/fileio/backends/local_backend.py", line 77, in put
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/mnt/azureml/cr/j/21f0a13bbecb4e2cb2bebba8539778b6/cap/data-capability/wd/outputs/epoch_1.pth'


Please add the code where you trying to save the checkpoint.

provide the path you are using.

According to this documentation  the work_dir is the path where all of your checkpoints and logs are saved.
So, give ./outputs as the working dir.
runner = Runner(
    model=MMResNet50(),
    work_dir='./outputs',
    .....
    )

Which will point to the current ExperimentRun output.
Also, check your dataset for caching it anywhere while training, because caching the large dataset to the folder and giving the same folder for outputs also gives this error.
If possible, change the output to default blob store.
outputs = {
    "outputs": Output(
        type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
        path=f"azureml://subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourcegroups/<resource_group>/workspaces/mljgs/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/dcid.{command_name}/work_dir",
        mode  =InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT
    ),
}

and give same to Runner working directory.
runner = Runner(
    model=MMResNet50(),
    work_dir=os.path.join(args.output_folder,'ooutputs/ck_point')
    .....
    )

You are not passing the input to training command job use below command in command parameter.
training_job = command(
    ....,
    command="python train.py --input_data ${{inputs.data}} --output_folder ${{outputs.outputs}}",
    .....

Refer this notebook on how to use inputs and outputs in training job.
At last, you try giving the path where your dataset is not present or cached
